# Reading user mouseclick position in haskells gloss

Tags: haskell, gloss

Edit:
So i followed your pointers and got to this point: (following the rules of play)

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.9.4.1/docs/Graphics-Gloss-Interface-Pure-Game.html

```
drawBoard :: IO ()
drawBoard = play (InWindow "Tic Tac Toe" (300,300)(10,10)) yellow 10 board (testBoard) (handleKeys) (iteration)

testBoard :: Board -> Picture
testBoard board = grid
    where
        grid =
            color black (line [ (-100, -300), (-100,  300) ])

iteration :: Float -> Board -> Board
iteration _ board = board 

handleKeys :: Event -> Board -> Board
handleKeys (EventKey (MouseButton LeftButton) Up _ (x, y)) board = board
handleKeys _ _ = board

board = []
```

And it correctly opens the window and draws a black line accoarding to my `testBoard` function.

What im not sure about now is how to pass a new board when I click a button. Do I create another function to draw the new board or how would I go on about drawing a new board when clicking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use [`play`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.9.4.1/docs/Graphics-Gloss.html#v:play) instead of `display`.

It explicitly takes an argument of type `Event -> world -> world` (`world` would be `Board` in your case) describing how to react to `Event`s.

Edit: Ok, I have implemented a toy example to show you how I'd structure my code. You can find it in a [self-contained gist](https://gist.github.com/gallais/0d61677fe97aa01a12d5) with the appropriate imports.

## What is the state of the system? How does it evolve?

The first thing you need to figure out is how to represent the state of the board. In a game of Tic-tac-toe, you have a bunch of *noughts* and a bunch of *crosses* at given *coordinates* (a pair of `Int`s equal to either -1, 0 or 1) on the board. You also have a current *player* (which will change after the next move). So let's start with that:

```
type Coordinates = (Int, Int)
data Player = Nought | Cross

data Board = Board
  { noughts :: [Coordinates]
  , crosses :: [Coordinates]
  , player  :: Player
  }
```

You can then describe various simple things. What should the *empty* board look like when you're beginning a match? What does a player's move (putting a new *token* on the board) do to the state of the system (it inserts the token in the list of the current player and then changes the current player to the adversary):

```
emptyBoard :: Board
emptyBoard = Board [] [] Nought

pushToken:: Coordinates -> Board -> Board
pushToken c b = case player b of
  Nought -> b { noughts = c : noughts b, player = Cross  }
  Cross  -> b { crosses = c : crosses b, player = Nought }
```

## How do we display the state to the user?

Next comes the problem of drawing a `Picture` corresponding to the current state. Here, I assume that the picture will be centered in `(0, 0)` which means that changing its size can be done by simply multiplying all the coordinates by a given constant. I will parameterise all my functions with a `Size` argument allowing me to tweak the size of the displayed board without any hassle.

```
type Size = Float

resize :: Size -> Path -> Path
resize k = fmap (\ (x, y) -> (x * k, y * k))
```

Noughts are easy to display: we can simply use a `thickCircle` of the right size and then translate them to their coordinate! Crosses are a bit harder to deal with because you have to combine 2 rectangles to draw them.

```
drawNought :: Size -> Coordinates -> Picture
drawNought k (x, y) =
  let x' = k * fromIntegral x
      y' = k * fromIntegral y
  in color green $ translate x' y' $ thickCircle (0.1 * k) (0.3 * k)

drawCross :: Size -> Coordinates -> Picture
drawCross k (x, y) =
  let x' = k * fromIntegral x
      y' = k * fromIntegral y
  in color red $ translate x' y' $ Pictures
     $ fmap (polygon . resize k)
     [ [ (-0.35, -0.25), (-0.25, -0.35), (0.35,0.25), (0.25, 0.35) ]
     , [ (0.35, -0.25), (0.25, -0.35), (-0.35,0.25), (-0.25, 0.35) ]
     ]
```

In order to draw the board, we draw a black grid and then populate it with the noughts and crosses:

```
drawBoard :: Size -> Board -> Picture
drawBoard k b = Pictures $ grid : ns ++ cs where

  ns = fmap (drawNought k) $ noughts b
  cs = fmap (drawCross k)  $ crosses b

  grid :: Picture
  grid = color black $ Pictures $ fmap (line . resize k)
       [ [(-1.5, -0.5), (1.5 , -0.5)]
       , [(-1.5, 0.5) , (1.5 , 0.5)]
       , [(-0.5, -1.5), (-0.5, 1.5)]
       , [(0.5 , -1.5), (0.5 , 1.5)]
       ]
```

## How do we react to inputs?

Now that we have a board and that we can display it, we just have to be able to grab user inputs and respond to them so that we have a working game.

Mouse clicks are received as a pair of floats corresponding to the position of the mouse in the drawing. We need to translate this position into appropriate coordinates. This is what `checkCoordinate` does: it divides a `Float` by the size we have picked for the drawing and checks which subdivision of the board that position corresponds to.

Here I use [`guard`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:guard), [`(<$)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Functor.html#v:-60--36-) and [(<|>)](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--124--62-) to have a declarative presentation of the various cases but you could use `if ... then ... else ...` if you wanted to.

```
checkCoordinate :: Size -> Float -> Maybe Int
checkCoordinate k f' =
  let f = f' / k
  in  (-1) <$ guard (-1.5 < f && f < -0.5)
  <|> 0    <$ guard (-0.5 < f && f < 0.5)
  <|> 1    <$ guard (0.5  < f && f < 1.5)
```

Finally, `handleKeys` can detect mouse clicks, check that they correspond to a position in the board and react appropriately by calling `pushToken`:

```
handleKeys :: Size -> Event -> Board -> Board
handleKeys k (EventKey (MouseButton LeftButton) Down _ (x', y')) b =
  fromMaybe b $ do
    x <- checkCoordinate k x'
    y <- checkCoordinate k y'
    return $ pushToken (x, y) b
handleKeys k _ b = b
```

## Putting it all together

We can then declare a `main` function creating the window, starting the game with an `emptyBoard`, displaying it using `drawBoard` and handling user inputs with `handleKeys`.

```
main :: IO ()
main =
  let window = InWindow "Tic Tac Toe" (300, 300) (10, 10)
      size   = 100.0
  in play window yellow 1 emptyBoard (drawBoard size) (handleKeys size) (flip const)
```

## What is there left to do?

I haven't enforced any of the game logic:

- player can put a token in a subdivision of the grid that's already occupied,
- the game does not detect when there is a winner
- there is no way to play multiple games in a row

Comment: Made an edit to my post after doing code in the direction you pointed me towards, now im just not sure how to update the board once i click :/

Comment: @darrrrUC Made an edit myself with a lot of code. Hope that helps you. ;)