# Haskell gloss example/skeleton

Tags: haskell, gloss

I am trying to use the gloss package in Haskell to make a game but find everything I read too simplistic or hard to read. I have seen

[What would be a typical game skeleton in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26120076/what-would-be-a-typical-game-skeleton-in-haskell)

which is a little useful but I am hoping for a little more information. Could someone provide any resources online with a slightly more complicated game with interacting elements. Code examples would be helpful too. I would like to have

```
main :: IO () 
main = do 
...play...
```

somewhere also with event handling/rendering and keyboard commands.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found some good examples:

http://andrew.gibiansky.com/blog/haskell/haskell-gloss/#_gloss

https://functional-programming.it.jyu.fi/master/pages/ProjectAsteroids.md

[Reading user mouseclick position in haskells gloss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35507997/reading-user-mouseclick-position-in-haskells-gloss)